# Doing a POST with cURL but server shows GET

Tags: post, curl, get

I am trying to do a simple POST.  I am using the code below but when I look at the server log it shows it is doing a POST instead of a GET.  Any idea why?  Code below.

THanks,
Mark

```
$url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/api.php';
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array('name' => 'Foo', 'file' => '@path\file.jpg');

  $headers = array(
    'Content-Type: image/jpeg'
  );


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '3');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER      ,1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$result = curl_exec( $ch );
```

Comment: Sorry what do you trying to do? You're saying you want to do a POST but thats the problem?

Comment: I don't know why you are setting 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' when you are only sending a string '@path\file.jpg'. If you are trying to upload an image, will need to load it into your php script and you will want to use post.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the line:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

it will be a POST request. If you remove that line it will be a GET request... Then you would need to put the data in the query instead.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your header confuses the server, if you need to Post it as multipart/form-data, don't set the header, and change your data array to this, it should help.

```
$data = array('name' => 'Foo', 'file' => '@path\file.jpg;type=image/jpeg');
```